# Can't infer an interesting pizza

Tags: sparql, jena, stardog, blazegraph, rdf4j

I have loaded the pizza ontology into Stardog and Blazegraph, along with some triples I authored, including a pizza with four toppings.  I have tried to make the toppings distinct, as @AKSW suggested.

The pizza ontology defines an interesting pizza as a pizza with at least three toppings.  I'm pretty sure I have OWL reasoning enabled, but **neither triplestore says that my pizza is interesting**.

***Can anybody show me settings that enable this inference in any freely available triplestore or point out what I've done wrong with my triples? 
 Especially, should I be able to infer that pizza instances, pizza classes, or both are "interesting"?***

**Interesting pizza definition:**

```
pizza:InterestingPizza rdf:type owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( pizza:Pizza
            [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                owl:onProperty pizza:hasTopping ;
                owl:minCardinality "3"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger
            ]
        ) ;
        rdf:type owl:Class
    ] ;
        rdfs:label "PizzaInteressante"@pt .
```

**My additional triples:**

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#> .

<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#marksPizzaClass>
  a owl:Class ;
  owl:equivalentClass [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasTopping> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#CaperTopping>
  ], [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasTopping> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#JalapenoPepperTopping>
  ], [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasTopping> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#LeekTopping>
  ], [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasTopping> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#MozzarellaTopping>
  ], [
    a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#hasTopping> ;
    owl:someValuesFrom <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#PineKernels>
  ] ;
  rdfs:subClassOf <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Pizza> ;
  rdfs:label "mark's pizza class" .

<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#marksPizzaClassMember>
  a owl:NamedIndividual, <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#marksPizzaClass> ;
  rdfs:label "a member of the mark's pizza class" .

<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#marksPizzaInstance>
  a owl:NamedIndividual, <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#Pizza> ;
  pizza:hasTopping pizza:marksPeppers, pizza:topping1, pizza:topping2, pizza:topping3, pizza:topping4 ;
  rdfs:label "mark's pizza instance" .

pizza:marksPeppers
  a owl:NamedIndividual, pizza:JalapenoPepperTopping ;
  rdfs:label "mark's special spicy jalapenos" .

pizza:topping1
  a owl:NamedIndividual, pizza:MozzarellaTopping ;
  rdfs:label "mark's semi secret topping one" .

pizza:topping2
  a owl:NamedIndividual, pizza:PineKernels ;
  rdfs:label "mark's semi secret topping two" .

pizza:topping3
  a owl:NamedIndividual, pizza:CaperTopping ;
  rdfs:label "mark's semi secret topping three" .

pizza:topping4
  a owl:NamedIndividual, pizza:LeekTopping ;
  rdfs:label "mark's semi secret topping four" .

[]
  a owl:AllDifferent ;
  owl:distinctMembers (
   pizza:marksPeppers
   pizza:topping1
   pizza:topping2
   pizza:topping3
   pizza:topping4
 ) .
```

**Query for any knowledge about a pizza instance with five distinct toppings:**

```
prefix pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
select *
where
{ pizza:marksPizzaInstance ?p ?o }
```

**Result from Stardog** *(I have manually replaced full URIs with prefixed URIs):*

```
+---------------------+----------------------------+
|          p          |             o              |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| pizza:hasIngredient | pizza:topping1             |
| pizza:hasIngredient | pizza:topping2             |
| pizza:hasIngredient | pizza:topping3             |
| pizza:hasIngredient | pizza:topping4             |
| pizza:hasIngredient | pizza:marksPeppers         |
| pizza:hasTopping    | pizza:topping1             |
| pizza:hasTopping    | pizza:topping2             |
| pizza:hasTopping    | pizza:topping3             |
| pizza:hasTopping    | pizza:topping4             |
| pizza:hasTopping    | pizza:marksPeppers         |
| rdfs:label          | mark's pizza instance      |
| rdf:type            | owl:Thing                  |
| rdf:type            | pizza:DomainConcept        |
| rdf:type            | pizza:Food                 |
| rdf:type            | pizza:Pizza                |
| rdf:type            | pizza:SpicyPizza           |
| rdf:type            | pizza:SpicyPizzaEquivalent |
| rdf:type            | pizza:CheeseyPizza         |
| rdf:type            | pizza:marksPizzaClass      |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

Stardog **has** inferred that my pizza has ingredients (because it has toppings), that my pizza is a food, and even that my pizza is spicy because it has Mark's jalapeno peppers as a topping.  But it hasn't inferred membership in the interesting pizza class.

Here are my Stardog reasoning settings:

```
Reasoning type: SL
Reasoning approximate: ON 
SameAs reasoning: FULL
TBox named graph: *
```

Comment: Hi Mark. I guess you now run into the fact that in OWL there is no Unique Names Assumption (UNA). That means a reasoner cannot assume from different names that individuals are different. Thus, you have to make the individuals explicitly different from each other (using `owl:differentFrom` pairwise or more convenient using `owl:allDifferent` with a list of individuals). In your case the toppings.

Comment: Something like that in turtle: `_:x rdf:type owl:AllDifferent .
_:x owl:members (:topping1 :topping2 :topping3 :topping4) `

Comment: I'm wondering why those guys didn't mention that - those are all real OWL experts. Maybe they overlooked the `minCardinality` which is mostly leading to those problems when using standard OWL reasoning.

Comment: No worries. One important thing to know: You should be aware of the different reasoning profiles - not sure which one you used in the triple store but as far as I know only Stardog supports full OWL reasoning. See https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles . For example, OWL QL does only support `owl:someValuesFrom` with `owl:Thing` as filler in SubClassOf axioms. This usally also affects Equivalence axioms which are just syntactic sugar. And it doesn't support `ObjectMinCardinality` in general.

Comment: @AKSW I think I did the AllDifferent like you suggested (see updated question), but I'm still not getting the desired inference.  I'm also loosing confidence that I know whether I should expect to see the inference for **1.** a pizza *class* that is equivalent to classes that have four different toppings **2.** an member of that class **or 3.** an instance of the generic class *pizza* that is directly asserted to have four different toppings.

Comment: Let me check Stardog - will take some time to setup the new version 5.0. In the meantime, can you try to use the `DL` profile? I'm wondering whether this will work. If so, we know that your desired inference is outside of the `SL` profile.

Comment: Mark, I checked your ontology in Protege. The axioms are enough to infer the your desired axiom, see https://pasteboard.co/Gz6yszu.png That means there might be a problem with the used reasoning profile.

Comment: An alternative - as you used `SL` profile - might be to add an SWRL rule, thus, please check my [modified ontology](http://txt.do/dkrh8)

Comment: You read my mind... SWRL is the next thing I was going to ask about.  I've never used it before.  How do I invoke your rule or query with it?  Either with the SWRL tab, or in a SAPRQL query?  I loaded your SWRL-ified version of the ontology and turned Hermit on, but didn't automagically see mark's pizza instance = interesting.

Comment: You mean in Protege? There you don't need the rule, just the class equivalence axiom. And then start the reasoner. Inference will work out of the box - click on the class `InterestingPizza`. Regarding triple stores, in particular, Stardog, my idea was to use the power of the Stardog `SL` profile which also includes support for SWRL rules. (or alternatively, Stardog rules which in fact are light-weight SPARQL BGPs)

Comment: In addition, SWRL rules are OWL axioms, i.e. you don't have to invoke them explicitly if the OWL reasoner supports them (Pellet and HermiT support a fragment of SWRL to ensure decidability)

Comment: Thanks so much.  It's a long holiday weekend for many of us in the US.  I'll be experimenting with this case and some related cases sporadically.  PS when do you sleep?  Is the @AKSW SO account for one person or your whole department?

Comment: Ok, good luck and let me know which way worked (best) for you :D I'll play around with Stardog inferencing support tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure that the `SL` profile doesn't contain some of the necessary axioms. They documentation states that it's a combination of the other profiles, but details are missing. PS: in Germany, most people will go to bed probably in an hour, but I prefer to "work" until midnight or beyond. No, this is my private account, but I know, the name is a bit misleading - maybe I should share the credentials accross our research group. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played a bit with Stardog 5.0 and got some more insights:

1. From an OWL DL view, the ontology is expressive enough to infer that

   ```
   pizza:marksPizzaInstance rdf:type pizza:InterestingPizza .
   ```

   This can be evaluated with Protege for example. A sample explanation that can be computed with the pretty cool Protege feature would be:
   [image]

   I could achieve the same in Stardog by enabling `DL` reasoning:

   ```
   bin/stardog-admin db offline pizzaDB
   bin/stardog-admin metadata set -o reasoning.type=DL pizzaDB
   bin/stardog-admin db online pizzaDB
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   +-------------------+-------------------------+
   |         p         |            o            |
   +-------------------+-------------------------+
   |  pizza:hasTopping |  pizza:topping1         |
   |  pizza:hasTopping |  pizza:topping2         |
   |  pizza:hasTopping |  pizza:marksPeppers     |
   |  pizza:hasTopping |  pizza:topping3         |
   |  pizza:hasTopping |  pizza:topping4         |
   |  rdf:type         |  pizza:Pizza            |
   |  rdf:type         |  owl:Thing              |
   |  rdf:type         |  pizza:InterestingPizza |
   +-------------------+-------------------------+
   ```
2. For the Stardog profile `SL` it doesn't work because the axiom is not in the profile. This can be recognized when looking into the Stardog log file which reports all ignored axioms:

   ```
   WARN  2017-07-03 09:54:51,219 [XNIO-1 task-6] com.clarkparsia.blackout.ProfileFilterBase:apply(39): 
   Not a valid SL axiom: 
   EquivalentClasses(pizza:InterestingPizza, and(pizza:Pizza, min(pizza:hasTopping,3,owl:Thing)))
   ```

   What I tried then is to add an SWRL rule since it's supported by the `SL` profile:

   ```
   Pizza(?x), hasTopping(?x, ?y1), hasTopping(?x, ?y2), hasTopping(?x, ?y3),  
   DifferentFrom (?y1, ?y2),  DifferentFrom (?y1, ?y3),  DifferentFrom (?y2, ?y3) 
   -> InterestingPizza(?x)
   ```

   Surprisingly, this did not work either. I guess I missed some important thing and I'm still investigating why this doesn't work.

   Lastly, I tried a Stardog rule instead of SWRL which has a pretty neat syntax close to SPARQL (BGPs are basically used):

   ```
   [] a rule:SPARQLRule ;
    rule:content """
       PREFIX :<http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
         IF {
               ?p a :Pizza ;
                  :hasTopping ?t1 , ?t2, ?t3
               FILTER(?t1 != ?t2 && ?t1 != ?t3 && ?t2 != ?t3)
            }
         THEN {
               ?p a :InterestingPizza
             }""" .
   ```

   This works as expected and the SPARQL query returns the desired inferred triple.

Comment: OK, using your input I can see my expected inference in Protege and Stardog (DL) now.  When I have some more free time, I'm going to experiment more with the different topics you covered.  (Especially trying in Blazegraph again.)  Thanks.

Comment: Note, the `DL` profile is more expensive, but with the Stardog rule you can use the `SL` profile. Indeed, this doesn't work for other triple stores. I never used Blazegraph, but I guess they support OWL QL (mostly used for query rewriting) which won't work with the equivalence axiom in your ontology.